# AngularJS module inside "root module"

Tags: angularjs, module

Is there a way to define an angular module inside another module ? I have a template in my web application which is called for almost every page of the application. In the template definition I set the ng-app. So for this ng-app I can declare the modules I need in all pages of the application (or almost every page). Now there are some modules I want to add only on specific pages. The problem is that in those pages I already have the ng-app of the template.

So is there a way to keep the ng-app as some kind of root ng-app which declared the modules I need everywhere and then add specific modules inside specific pages too ?

That means is it possible to do something like this:

```
 <div ng-app="rootApp">
      <div ng-app="specificApp">
         ... 
      </div>
 </div>
```

The rootApp contains the module that are declared in my template, that are use in all the pages, and the specifiApp contains the modules I need only in one specific page.

Thanks !

[EDIT] Bootstrap attempt:

```
 var reportHolidaysByEmployeeApp = angular.module('reportHolidaysByEmployeeApp', ['fitnetApp', 'ui.bootstrap']);
 angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("reportHolidaysByEmployeeApp"), ['reportHolidaysByEmployeeApp']);

 reportHolidaysByEmployeeApp.controller('ReportHolidaysByEmployeeCtrl', function($scope, $filter, $timeout) {
```

fitnetApp is the global Module I load on the html tag in every page

Answer (score 0):

If you are having separate controllers for your pages[views] , add dependency in your controller module to [rootApp] or [spcificApp] as your page needs.

```
$routeProvider.when('/view1',{
      template:
      controller:view1controller
})

if u need rootApp as dependency in view1 page

in your controller module

angular.module('GlobalCtrl',['rootApp'])
.controller('view1controller')
```

'

Answer (score 0):

> Only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML
>   document. The first ngApp found in the document will be used to define
>   the root element to auto-bootstrap as an application. To run multiple
>   applications in an HTML document you must manually bootstrap them
>   using angular.bootstrap instead. AngularJS applications cannot be
>   nested within each other. --
>   http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngApp

See also

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/lhbrIG5aBX4/4hYnzq2eGZwJ
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.bootstrap

Comment: I tred to bootstrap but this works only if the first ng-app is closed before the second one. So there is no way to add a new ng-app inside of the global one in order to add new specific modules to a specific page ?

Comment: I edited the main topic. The error is `Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'ReportHolidaysByEmployeeCtrl' is not a function, got undefined`

The div is defined like this: `<div id="reportHolidaysByEmployeeApp" ng-controller="ReportHolidaysByEmployeeCtrl">`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two ng-app in a single web page.
If you need to add dependency module on specific page use

`angular.module('reportHolidaysByEmployeeApp').requires.push('thirdpartymodule');`

This will dynamically inject dependency in your already running angular application.